# Server app as WPF or as MVC4/IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sockets, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple server app that I need to re-write.  Basically, uses async TCPSockets to allow multiple clients to connect & communicate asynchronously.  Right now it is running as a winforms app & is managed as a windows service.  I'm trying to decide if I should rebuild it in a similar way using WPF, or should I rebuild as an IIS MVC4 WebAPI app.  I like all of the monitoring options & memory management built into IIS.  This is definitely more familiar territory to me.

I'll need a nice GUI interface to see realtime statistics but this should be do-able as a web app.  Is there any reason I wouldn't use MVC4 web API?

Comment: `I'll need a nice GUI interface` - [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19406501/643085) the explanation of the difference between WPF and web applications in general.

Comment: Who are you expecting to use the app? How many people? How distributed are the users? As someone who programs in both WPF and ASP.net I have to disagree with HighCore's "Everything HTML sucks"

Comment: @Shoe don't forget to mention javascript. It's not the (really lacking) HTML that I'm about, but mostly the horrible untyped javascript stuff where you don't get any intellisense. I'd rather go back to GW-Basic.

Comment: @HighCore The combination of using the razor engine plus jquery cuts down on most of the javascript. It's a lot easier to screw up without careful planning and being skilled and patient. You have to remember that web applications as a concept are at best half the age that traditional applications, making them the "Wild West" of development. I wouldn't throw the baby and bathwater out, especially for non-enterprise solutions.